# raise event on pressing enter in datagridview cells

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to get the value of the first cell of a row in the datagridview on selecting any cell of the row of the datagridview and pressing enter. How to do it?

Comment: Which UI framework? And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You may handle DataGridView.KeyDown event. For example:

```
    object firstCellValue = null;
    private void dgv_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            firstCellValue = dgv.Rows[dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
        }
    }
```